# How do I get cross entropy of two distributions with Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, statistics

In TensorFlow we have `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` which only allows you to use your predicted logits and the index of gold labels (one-hot). However, sometimes we want to compute the cross entropy of two distributions, i.e., the gold standard is not one-hot. How can I achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Actually [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/soft) does not impose the restriction that `labels` must be on-hot encoded, so you can go ahead and use non-one-hot `label` vectors. You might be confusing this with [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) which *does* impose this restriction.

To the other part of your question– if you want to compute the cross-entropy between two normalized distributions in tensors `p` and `q`, you can use the formula yourself if you make sure use `tf.math.xlogy` so that you get zero for `x=0` and `y=0`. So, letting `p` and `q` be two tensors representing normalized distributions across axis `1` you would have–

```py
ce = - tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.xlogy(p, q), axis=1)
```

On the other hand, its likey that you actually have some `logits` that are output by a model (rather than a normalized distribution `q` that is computed from the logits). In this case it would be better to compute the cross-entropy by applying log-softmax of your logits

```py
ce = - tf.reduce_sum(p * tf.nn.log_softmax(logits, axis=1), axis=1)
```

(thereby avoiding [numerical instability](http://www.nowozin.net/sebastian/blog/streaming-log-sum-exp-computation.html) of explicitly computing a softmax distribution and then immediately taking it's log). In the typical ML setting `p` would be your "labels" and `q` & `logits` is the output of your model. Note that this works fine for non-one-hot labels `p`.